# Form Method.GET: Only show populated inputs in Query String?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in an ASP.NET MVC application and have a data table. Above the data table I have a form with various inputs to filter the table.

The form is using the `GET` method to transfer the form data to the server, which works fine, however even though I only want to filter on one thing (e.g. Manufacturer name), all the other input parameters are posted into the query string too! Like so:

```
http://localhost/mysite/page1?Tab=Pending&SortBy=&SortAscending=False&Manufacturer=Toyota&Model=&RegNumberFilter=
```

As you can see, I only have the Manufacturer filled, but everything else gets submitted too! Is there an easy way I can clean up my URL so that only filters that are set are displayed in the query string?

My filter form is below:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "page1", FormMethod.Get, new { @role = "form", @class = "form-inline" }))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("Tab", Model.Tab);
        @Html.Hidden("SortBy", Model.SortBy);
        @Html.Hidden("SortAscending", Model.SortAscending);
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="Manufacturer">Manufacturer</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Manufacturer, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Manufacturer" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="model">Model</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.model, Model.model, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="RegNumberFilter">Reg Number</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RegNumberFilter, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Reg Number" })
        </div>

        <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clear_form_elements(this.form)" value="Clear Filter" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Apply</button>
        </div><!-- .btn-toolbar -->
    }
</div>
```

Comment: you used Post not GEt in  that case url will be clean

Comment: I must use `GET` because I want the URL to determine the filtering in effect. This way people can share the URL and see the same thing. So unfortunately this must remain in `GET`. Thanks

Comment: Why not just put the manufacturer textbox in the form? Could you show how you build your outgoing `URL`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the Manufacturer is already a textbox inside the filter form. Code now added. Thanks

Comment: try disabling controls which you don't want to include in URL

Comment: How do you disable a control? Is it a HTML attribute? or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are still looking for an answer to this, like I was, I've got a very quick and rough way of handling just such a case myself now.

```
function submitSearch() {
    $('#tblSearchForm input[type="text"]').each(function () { if (this.value == "") this.remove(); });
    $('#tblSearchForm select').each(function () { if (this.selectedOptions.length > 0 && this.selectedOptions[0].value == "") this.selectedIndex = -1; });
}
```

And in the form's anonymous object containing the htmlAttributes simply include:

```
 onSubmit = "submitSearch()"
```

as an extra key/value.

It's quick and dirty but it does the job very nicely. There's probably something better than the sledgehammer "this.remove()" and I'd be glad to use something more appropriate if it's out there.

Edit:
For those having to provide IE8 compatibility the *this.remove()* will not work... use ***this.parentNode.removeChild(this)*** instead.